# Problem Installing MacTeX-2011-1 on OSX 10.4.11

Tags: installing, mactex

I have a problem installing the MacTeX-2011-1.mpkg on my macbook (OS X 10.4.11). The first few steps (like Software License Agreement etc.) are working, but when it comes to the "proper" installation it fails:

The screen shot shows the problem: After choosing the volume to install onto, the installer asks whether I want to check some boxes  (for example "Tex Live 2011" etc., (überspringen = engl. skip)). When I try to check the boxes nothing happens, they don't "take" the check. When I just press the button "installieren" (install) the box on the top appears. It says "You cannot continue. The software for the installation is missing". Does anyone know what to do?

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: Unfortunately, MacTeX 2011 cannot run on 10.4; the developers think that maintaining so many different versions (each requiring some adjustment when compiling executables) is too much of a labour.

Comment: Indeed, see the banner at http://www.tug.org/mactex/2011/: "[ for Mac OS 10.5, 10.6, and 10.7 --- PPC and Intel ]"

Comment: Also, see http://www.tug.org/mactex/2011/faq/3-4.html

Comment: Thank you very much! Somehow I overlooked that peace of information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MacTeX 2011 is for OS X 10.5 and higher.

> This distribution requires Mac OS 10.5 Leopard or higher; see links below for Mac OS 10.3 or 10.4.

See the [homepage](http://www.tug.org/mactex/2011/) for more information.

Comment: @all: Thank you very much. Now I installed the right version and it works. Juhu!!!

Comment: @Philip: Your welcome! I’m not sure if this works, but I guess with the TeX Live Utility (default installed at `Macintosh HD/Applications/TeX/`/`Macintosh HD/Programme/TeX/`) you should be able to update at least the packages to the latest version. I hope that the newer packages work with the older programs (like `pdflatex` etc.).